# Summing multiple index match formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I am not sure if there is a cleaner way to do this, but I am wondering if it is possible to repeat an index match with multiple different look-up values?

=INDEX(Financials!$B$10:$XFD$10,MATCH('Model'!$G$2,Financials!$B$102:$XFD$102,0))
+INDEX(Financials!$B$10:$XFD$10,MATCH('Model'!$G$3,Financials!$B$102:$XFD$102,0))
+INDEX(Financials!$B$10:$XFD$10,MATCH('Model'!$G$4,Financials!$B$102:$XFD$102,0))
+INDEX(Financials!$B$10:$XFD$10,MATCH('Model'!$G$5,Financials!$B$102:$XFD$102,0))

As you can see, I am doing 4 different index match formulas on the same arrays and only changing the look-up value. Perhaps there is a way to insert an array as the look-up value. Any thoughts welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more details on how your dataset looks like? I am not sure what exactly you are looking for in your index match function - maybe sumif & or function would already do the trick?

Comment: Try, =SUM(INDEX(Financials!$B$10:$XFD$10,N(IF(1,MATCH(Model!$G$2:$G$5,Financials!$B$102:$XFD$102,0))))) array formula (CSE entry)

Comment: If the lookups are unique in the list, use SUMIFS: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Financials!$B$10:$XFD$10,Financials!$B$102:$XFD$102,'Model'!$G$2:$G$5))`

Comment: @daveyjonezz if you do not have office 365 then you would need to array enter the formula provided by bosco_yip with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you! that worked like a charm. If you want to post your comment as an answer then I can mark it completed.

Answer (score 1):

**Variations:**

Several methods will achieve this, depending on scope/intent (screenshot below refers, [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98BepqDQBqUoWezRT?e=RKMWWE) is a shared workbook fyi):

1] `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($B$10:$CB$10,$B$11:$CB$11,$G$2:$G$5))`

Courtesy @ScottCraner, this 'does the job'; albeit in the spirit of creating a 'cleaner way', I prefer the following which has greater parsimony / simplicity (i.e. less 'expensive' re time/computation, easier to audit/communicate etc.) & achieves same objective/result:

2a]  `=SUM(B10:CB10*(G2:G5=$B$11:$CB$11))`

Perhaps more intuitive is the following, slight variation to above:

2b] `=SUM(IF($B$11:$CB$11=$G$2:$G$5,B10:CB10,""))`

You'll struggle with the index function if you wish to sum all values for which there is a much (by the sounds of it, you do, in which case the function would take the form of a filter which would require slightly more complexity in relation to [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0zJm.png), but would on par with [1](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98BepqDQBqUoWezRT?e=RKMWWE), assuming the Office 365 pre-requisite for filter is not an issue):

3] `=SUM(FILTER(B10:CB10,ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$11:$CB$11,$G$2:$G$5,0))))`

Of course, if you really want to reproduce what you have but in a 'cleaner' way, you would deploy the following:

4] `=SUM(INDEX($G$13:$CG$13,MATCH(F8:F11,$G$14:$CG$14,0)))`

Of course, this abstracts from being able to deal with multiple common values.

[image: Screenshot of linked workbook]

[image: Methods 1-4: Pros | Cons]